# How do I migrate from TFS to Visual Studio Online using the OpsHub Utility?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I am attempting to migrate to VSO from TFS and receiving the following errors:

I have administrative rights in both VSO and TFS.

Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Switch the the TFS Integration Platform.

Answer (score 2):

Here you find answers to your all queries.

**Administrative Right(s):**

The OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility requires that the user that is used to create the Visual Studio Online End Point is a member of the Project Collection Administrator Group.
To grant the user that particular right, follow the following link.
http://www.opshub.com/ohrel/Resources/TFS/permissions.php?page=admin

**Template Customization:**

You are facing template customization error due to you have configured custom field(s) at your source end. 
& such field(s) are not exist on your target VSO.
Solution for this is to delete the custom field(s) at your source end & revalidate again to processed further using migration utility. Migration on customized process templates are not supported through free utility.

You can revert customization incase you want to continue your migration with free utility with the help of following article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236909.aspx

You can use power tools for quick configuration of custom fields
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

**Missing Link Type(s) Warning:**

You are seeing link type warning because your target VSO instance is not having Affects and Affected by link types. Still you can continue the migration with warning, in this case your Affects & Affected by link type(s) will migrated as “Related” link type.

Alternative solution is to create new project with CMMI template in your target end. This will automatically add the missing Affects & Affected By link type(s) in target VSO. After doing this revalidate again and proceed further without warning. You can remove newly created CMMI project once you are able to see Affects, Affected by link types in you project.

Comment: You can also use the TFS Integration Tools to do the migration without subjecting your source users to disruption. You can create a mapping between the template types. Not as easy, but more scalable.